# Character Arithmetic in Swift

Tags: swift

Consider the following code snippet to convert a hex `Character` to an integer value

```
extension Character {

    var hexValue : UInt {
        let zero : Character = "0"
        let nine : Character = "9"
        let a : Character = "a"
        let f : Character = "f"
        let A : Character = "A"
        let F : Character = "F"

        if self >= zero && self <= nine {
            return self - zero
        }
        if self >= a && self <= f {
            return self - a + 10
        }
        if self >= A && self <= F {
            return self - A + 10
        }

        return 0
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the Swift compiler doesn't like the `+`/`-` operations on `Character`.

How can I do arithmetic operations on Characters in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer when I dug around the Swift headers. We can use `UnicodeScalar` for this, like so:

```
UnicodeScalar("a").value
```

`value` will give you the character integer value

To convert an arbitrary `Character` you can do this

```
let s = String(myChar).unicodeScalars
let i = scalars[s.startIndex].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try NSScanner:

```
var hexChar = "A"
var hexValue:UInt32 = 0
let scanner = NSScanner(string: hexChar)
scanner.scanHexInt(&hexValue)

println(hexValue) // prints 10
```